# Load csv from S3 to Oracle

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, oracle11g

I have a requirement to load a csv file which is kept in AWS S3 location into Oracle table.

I saw the `LOAD DATA` statement in the Oracle documentation [page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.6-en/load-data.html) (code mentioned below) but there is no option to load data from AWS S3 to Oracle table. Does any one know if there is a feature in Oracle to do this?

```
LOAD DATA
    [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL]
    INFILE 'file_name'
    [REPLACE | IGNORE]
    INTO TABLE tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
    [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
        [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
        [ESCAPED BY 'char']
    ]
    [LINES
        [STARTING BY 'string']
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    ]
    [IGNORE number {LINES | ROWS}]
    [(col_name_or_user_var
        [, col_name_or_user_var] ...)]
    [SET col_name={expr | DEFAULT}
        [, col_name={expr | DEFAULT}] ...]
```

Comment: Is it large file? The oracle is RDS at AWS?

Comment: Nope. Oracle is not at AWS, it is in on-premise server

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, if you have a CSV file, then **SQL*Loader** is a tool to be used.

It is installed along with every Oracle database (so, if you have access to an on-premise server, you have it). Even better, you can use that tool from your own PC; SQL*Loader is part of Oracle's *utilities*, can be installed from the Client software. Or, if you install Oracle XE (Express Edition) on your PC, it also contains it.

Shortly: you'd create a *control file* which specifies data source (your CSV file), target table, which columns you'll be loading, etc. Then run it from the operating system command prompt and that's it.

SQL*Loader is really, really fast.

---

Another option is to use **external tables** feature; its *drawback* is that you do have to have access to the database server (actually, to a directory - an Oracle object which points to a file system directory which is *usually* located on the database server). If you aren't a DBA, you'll have to talk to one as they have to grant you required privileges.

If you use it, then you'd access the CSV file from SQL, i.e. you can query the file as if it was an ordinary Oracle table and use e.g.

```
insert into target_table (col1, col2, ...) 
select col1, col2, ... from csv_file_as_external_table
```